# Sponza scene with more physically motivated materials fit for physically based renderers

Tags: sponza

I've tried it with the default values and a lighting model copied straight from [here](http://seblagarde.wordpress.com/2011/08/17/hello-world/), but the results were ludicrous. Basically since everything is way too shiny (high specular material values), most of the screen is very white unless I set the light intensity to a very small value or manually change roughness of the materials to very high values, in which case everything looks like someone spent years polishing the stuff.

Is there a version of the scene around with more physically motivated materials? Or am I just using them/interpreting them wrong?

The reason I even ask is because the scene seems to be very popular as testmaterial for global illumination algorithms, where physically based lighting seems to be commonplace.

Comment: Found this link made by someone with the same problem: https://www.alexandre-pestana.com/pbr-textures-sponza/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such a Sponza scene doesn't exist. Seems like all demos just use the basic Crytek Sponza model, some with the big flag in the middle removed.